# Замена больших букв в строке маленькими с точкой впереди

Tags: java, отладка

Например "Sweet" -> ".sweet" или "FeDex" -> ".fe.dex"

Я нашла следующий код, но он не работает.

```
public String readString(String toRead) {
    char[] array = toRead.toCharArray();
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(array[i]) && i == 0 || i > 0 && 
                !Character.isDigit(array[i-1]) && Character.isDigit(array[i])) {
            String indicatesNumbers = "\u283C";
            String key = Character.toString(array[i]);
            result += indicatesNumbers + map.get(key);
            continue;
        }
        if(Character.isDigit(array[i]) && i > 0) {
            String key = Character.toString(array[i]);
            result += map.get(key);

        } else {
            result += array[i]; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Подскажите, как добиться правильной замены больших букв маленькими с точкой впереди?

Comment: Вы этот код просто взяли выдрали откуда-то и выложили тут не разобравшись? А собственно говоря в чем заключается Ваша проблема?

Comment: *"Fedex" на ".fe.dex"*. Почему перед `d` тоже точка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вашего кода правильный ход мыслей,(до некоторой степени) но нужно немного "дожать";

В контексте конкретно той задачи, которую вы обрисовали, могу предложить следующую функцию:

```
    String toLowerWithDot(String inputString) {
    //StringBuilder просто быстрее работает, можно использовать и просто String 
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    //Разбиваем строку на массив символов
    char[] lettersArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < lettersArray.length; i++) {
        //Если символ в верхнем регистре..
        if(Character.isUpperCase(lettersArray[i])) {
            //добавляем его в результирующую строку, но с точкой, и в нижнем регистре
            outputBuilder.append("." + Character.toLowerCase(lettersArray[i]));
        } else {
            //(а если нет, то просто добавляем)
            outputBuilder.append(lettersArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return outputBuilder.toString();
}
```

p.s. запускабельный пример использования- https://pastebin.com/YNNachjQ

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @MarinaGB Рад помочь :)

Comment: а как сделать наоборот? ;)

Comment: @MarinaGB маленькие с точкой в большие? Не сильно сложнее - https://pastebin.com/D6DPJDWt (дополнил код обратной функцией, запускабельно)